# Maintining session using play2 framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to `Play2` framework. I am trying to maintain session inside my web App.
But there is some certain problem, Session is maintained after user login to web app and when user try to login to Google Sign (i am using google analytics) then when user press allow button then session becomes `null`

How to maintain the session? so that it doesn't get destroy 
Here is some relevant code

This code is used when user press login button

```
public Result login() {
    Map<String, String[]> formData = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
    String email[] = formData.get("email");
    String password[] = formData.get("password");
    if (email == null || email.equals("") || password == null || password.equals("")) {
        flash("error", "Invalid email/password!");
    } else {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setEmail(email[0]);
        userDTO.setPassword(password[0]);
        userDTO = accountMGR.signin(userDTO);
        if (userDTO != null)
            session("user", Json.toJson(userDTO).toString());
        else
            flash("error", "Invalid email/password!");
    }
    return redirect(com.softoven.ultron.controllers.routes.AccountCTRL.index());
}

public Result logout() {
    session().clear();
    return redirect(com.softoven.ultron.controllers.routes.AccountCTRL.index());
}
```

and this is the code which runs when user presses google sign in button

```
public Result callback() {
        JsonNode jsonNode = Json.parse(session("user"));
        UserDTO userDTO = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, UserDTO.class);

        if (userDTO.getRole().getType().equals(RoleDTO.EnRoleType.ADMIN.toString()))
            return redirect(com.softoven.ultron.controllers.routes.AccountCTRL.index());
        if (request().queryString().get("code") != null && request().queryString().get("state") != null && request().queryString().get("state")[0].equals(session("state"))) { // Check if he/she is authorized
            session().remove("state");
            Analytics analytics = setAnalytics(userDTO, request());
            session("analytics", Json.toJson(analytics).toString());
            return redirect(com.softoven.ultron.controllers.routes.AccountCTRL.index());
        } else {  // Create Authorization URL
            String url = helper.buildLoginUrl();
            session("state", helper.getStateToken());
            return redirect(url);
        }
    }
```

this particularly line creates problem

```
JsonNode jsonNode = Json.parse(session("user"));
```

Even though i am setting the session in above method `login()`